# How to generate a JSP file for a wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, wsdl

I have a wsdl file, that i am writing a web client for

however, sometimes i just need to test if the given method works

I want to invoke this method with minimal user interface and see if the result i get is the desired result.

I want to replace the "Hi perhaps there will be a form here to invoke this wsdl"
[image]

with an actual form that will allow me to do this

I know how to replace the page itself - the question is WITH WHAT
is there a way to autogenerate these forms, from the given wsdl file ?

Answer (score 0):

The method I prefer to test wsdl is to use eclipse:

1. Switch to Java EE perspective
2. Select Run -> Launch the Web Services Explorer
   [image]
3. Select WSDL explorer from top right buttons (A) and select WSDL Main from navigator (B)
   [image]
4. Enter WSDL URL (eg: `http://mycompany/somecoolservice?wsdl`) and hit Go.
5. WSDL explorer will display available operations. If you select one of them it will build a form for you to test

Comment: the problem is i need to download files with the wsdl, this method makes it run on the internal eclipse tomcat, and that one disallows creating files at "catalina base" because catalina base for it is inside the metadata plugins folder